# What is the return type of List.generate of Flutter when no type is specified?

Tags: flutter, dart

From: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/passing-data

```
final todos = List.generate(
  20,
  (i) => Todo(
    'Todo $i',
    'A description of what needs to be done for Todo $i',
  ),
);
```

This says a type has to be there: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/List/List.generate.html

What is the return type of List.generate of Flutter when no type is specified?

Comment: Try print(todos.runtimeType).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in this case `List.generate` will return `List<Todo>`. It is a good practice to give the type of the list.

```
final todos = List<Todo>.generate(
  20,
  (i) => Todo(
    'Todo $i',
    'A description of what needs to be done for Todo $i',
  ),
);
```

If you want any object's type just simply use `yourobject.runtimeType`